# is Psylocke's Psi Blade visible to others?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

In either 616 or Ultimate universe, is Psylocke's psionic blade visible to normal people? Since it's psychic energy, I've always just guessed it was only visible to those with physic preys
Powers, like Xavier and Jean. The comics and cartoons often employ visual effects for certain characters powers for the viewers benefit, as those powers tend to be invisible in nature (Xavier,  Magneto,  Jean, basically any n-path, n-kinetic or magic based character, spidey sense).

In a similar fashion, does Iron Fist glowy fist of iron just an audience benefit or does it glow in universe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### In the early depictions it was not clear whether Psylocke's powers had a visual element capable of being seen. Later depictions as her powers grew more powerful and had a telekinetic element, her power became visible to the naked eye.

- This is mostly seen as the butterfly image around the face of the subject and the target of her telepathic interaction early in the character's history.

[image]

- Later, when her psychic powers became able to be focused into her psychic knife and later her psychic katana, both were visible to people without psychic abilities.

[image]

- Notice the swordsman are able to see and attempt to block the blade but are foiled by its ability to slice through and destroy their weapons. They would have to see it to consider blocking it.

[image]

> - Psylocke's telekinetic manifestations produce visible radiance in the physical world. Thus, she can use her psychic katana as a makeshift light source in areas of darkness. Her telekinetic katana is strong enough to harm other beings more powerful than herself. **[REF: Uncanny X-Men #472](http://marvel.wikia.com/Elizabeth_Braddock_(Earth-616))**

Comment: I don't know, the second cap doesn't back up that statement.

Comment: It casts light and shadows: 3rd panel on the left. That should be imply it creates light enough to indicate it CAN be seen.

Comment: @Thaddeus - I don't see the shadow, and the pink light might be there so **we** can see it.  Even in the third picture, the fact that the bad guys are trying to block the blade might be explained by the fact that they can see her hand coming and deduce where the blade is.  I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying that the pictures don't prove anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think during the 2013 Psylocke series it wasn't made explicit but it was shown in panels that her psionic weapons do cast light and shadow.

I can't find the panel but I think in Astonishing X-Men 12 or 13 Wolverine says something about the color of her blades, or he says something like "this looks like one of Psylocke's blades", indicating that he has previously seen one and is making the comparison.

Comment: I've got both of those issues and I can't find that panel.